# Adding href into li class="email"

Tags: html, class, email, nested, href

Happy New Year!

Not sure if you all can help me out - I am FAR from a programmer! - but totally stumped. I can usually muddle my way through changes like this but, lost with this one.

If I look at my site using Firebug - and see the code below - and edit, within the Firebug
console the "email" line and change it to:

```
<a href="mailto:support@technologysolutionslive.com?subject=HELP">Send Email</a>
```

it works - just the way I want.

But for the life of me I can not find the file/where/what to edit in order to add this html
to make that line of text clickable for my users.

Can someone point the way to where I might find this file?
Thanks!
Rob

```
<div id="top-bar" class="text-center top-bar-hide" role="complementary"          style="visibility: visible; margin-top: 0px;">
<div class="wf-wrap">
<div class="wf-table wf-mobile-collapsed">
<div class="wf-td">
<div class="mini-contacts wf-float-left">
<ul>
<li class="email">support@technologysoloutionslive.com</li>
<li class="skype">TSLHelpdesk</li>
<li class="clock">Standard SLA support is available M-F, 7AM-7PM EST</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="soc-ico show-round">
</div>
</div>
</div>
<span class="act"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Is this what you want?

```
<li class="email"><a href="mailto:support@technologysolutionslive.com?subject=HELP">Send Email</a></li>
```

Comment: Yes, exactly! Can you tell me where to go, what file, I need to edit to do this?

Comment: All you need to do is replace this line: `<li class="email">support@technologysoloutionslive.com</li>` in the block of code you posted.

Comment: Yes, I know :) But the block of code I pasted is from the Firebug display…I need to know where to find the code - the actual file the code resides in that I can edit. Thanks!

Comment: I can't tell what the name of the file is from your original post, but it's the same as the name in the address bar of Firefox. All you need to do is open the file in a text editor instead of Firefox.

Comment: Hmm…that just lists to css files - the "main" and a "custom" one. And, in neither of those files can I find the line to edit. The code -  <li class="email"> - is not in either of those files.

Comment: It should be an html file (.htm or .html), the exact same name as appears in your browser's URL bar when you have the page open. Something like `file:///C:/temp/index.html`.

Comment: Hi KGH, Just noticed your last post - sorry about that! I don't have any html/htm files other than a readme.html. I'm using Wordpress and have gone through the WP files and the theme files I'm running - no htmls. I've even tried to identify the template, of the main page, within the theme…no go. And, I've run a search, on my system - not the live site - of the theme and Wordpress files and the only place that makes mention of the (li class="email"*.* is in the main.css file. Somebody said because it's all php and java I need to find the java script that controls the output…

Comment: I see. Wordpress is more complex than if you were making your own site with HTML-- I'm not experienced with it enough to know what you need to do in this case, but you might want to try asking about Wordpress specifically.